# How to handle certificates in case of the OpenSSLerror in Python (Windows 10)?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, openssl, certificate

I am new here and new on python scripting with the following problem and hope somebody can help me somehow.
I made a script in Python for parsing an internal corporate link where is stored a JSON file with internal exchange rates. The data is loaded into a dataframe and saved in an Excel file.
Detials to mention:
- The certificate was saved using the web-browser;
- I don't have full rights on the PC;
- OS: Windows10
- The certificate is PEM format (I have checked according the suggestions for other questions)

The problem is that the script is failing on certificate verification getting the OpenSSL error (provided below). The script is working only if I am using the option Verify=False.
I have tried all founded solutions for other similar questions without any successful result.
I couldn't figure out what the error exactly means and where could the issue.

Thank you very much in advance.

**OpenSSL error: OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('PEM routines', 'get_name', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file', 'PEM lib')]**

```
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import os

certfx = os.getcwd() + '\\rootfxCert.cer'

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\user','password')
session.cert = certfx

from_date = input("Insert start date (YYYY-MM-DD): > ")
to_date = input("Insert end date (YYYY-MM-DD): > ")

df = pd.DataFrame()

currList = ["EUR", "USD"]

for date in pd.date_range(start=from_date,end=to_date):
    for curr in currList:
        strDate = str(date)[:10]
        url = "https://apex.sample.grp/api/exrates/daily-rates/" + strDate + "/" + curr
        source = session.get(url, cert = session.cert)#, verify = certfx)  
        data = source.json()
        new_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['items'], orient='columns', dtype=None)
        df = df.append(new_df)

df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index = False)
```